# Can't fetch the titles from a webpage

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I've written a script in vba in combination with `IE` to get the `titles` of diferent `charts` from a webpage but I'm not being able to. It seems I've used right `class` names along with `tag` names to reach the content but no dice. It doesn't throw any error either.

This is my approach so far:

```
Sub GetTitle()
    Const Url As String = "https://www.fbatoolkit.com/"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate Url
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
    End With

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    For Each post In Html.getElementsByClassName("chart")
        With post.getElementsByTagName("text")
          If .Length Then R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = .item(0).innerText
        End With
    Next post
End Sub
```

The titles are like below which are visible above each charts:

```
Toys & Games
Health & Household
```

I'm not expecting any solution related to `selenium`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of cheat to be honest. Consider it a placeholder until I find a better way as I am guessing you specifically want to access ***those*** titles.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument, titles(), i As Long
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.fbatoolkit.com/"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set html = .document
        titles = GetTitles(html.body.innerHTML, "id=""visualization([^""]*)")
        For i = LBound(titles) To UBound(titles)
            Debug.Print titles(i)
        Next
        .Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetTitles(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal sPattern As String) As Variant
    Dim Matches As Object, iMatch As Object, s As String, arrMatches(), i As Long
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = sPattern
        If .test(inputString) Then
            Set Matches = .Execute(inputString)
            For Each iMatch In Matches
                If iMatch.SubMatches(0) <> vbNullString Then
                    ReDim Preserve arrMatches(i)
                    arrMatches(i) = Replace$(Replace$(iMatch.SubMatches(0), Chr$(95), Chr$(32)), Chr$(32) & Chr$(32), Chr$(32) & Chr$(38) & Chr$(32))
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next iMatch
        End If
    End With
    GetTitles = arrMatches
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @QHarr, for your suggestion. I didn't notice that I could have patsed `ids` to get the titles. How come I missed them!!

Comment: Okay, now we can delete commnts. I will paste here a link how I optimozed If you like. Once again `I + lrow` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Althogh this answer is fully influenced by `QHarr`, I thought to publish it for future readers. Making use of `IDS` is the best policy here. The following solution almost resembles the category names.

Here it is:

```
Sub GetChartInfo()
    Const Url As String = "https://www.fbatoolkit.com/"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument
    Dim itemvisibility As Object, otitle As Object, I&

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate Url
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
    End With

    Do: Set itemvisibility = Html.querySelectorAll("div[class='chart-container']"): DoEvents: Loop While itemvisibility.Length <= -1

    With Html.querySelectorAll("div[class='chart-container']")
        For I = 0 To .Length - 1
            Do: Set otitle = .Item(I).querySelector(".chart"): DoEvents: Loop While otitle Is Nothing
            Cells(I + 1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Replace(Replace(Split(otitle.getAttribute("id"), "visualization_")(1), "__", " "), "_", " "))
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice way of doing